# The great Britain or just great Britain

Tags: articles

What is the error in the from following sentence?

> Many overseas students attend colleges in the Great Britain.

On many of the sites I found that **the** should be removed before Great Britain. But ngram shows **the** is used before Great Britain.

Comment: It's ***The** United Kingdom*, but there's no article before ***Britain*** (whether preceded by ***Great*** or not).

Answer (score 1):

"Great Britain" is a proper noun, and does not take an article (zero determiner).

I looked up "the great britain" and "great britain" (case-insensitive) on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20great%20britain%2Cgreat%20britain&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthe%20great%20britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20Great%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Great%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHE%20GREAT%20BRITAIN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgreat%20britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGreat%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGREAT%20BRITAIN%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cthe%20great%20britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20Great%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Great%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHE%20GREAT%20BRITAIN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgreat%20britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGreat%20Britain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGREAT%20BRITAIN%3B%2Cc0), and could not reproduce your results.